# ng2-charts live data animation

Tags: jquery, angularjs, charts, highcharts, ng2-charts

I'm using Angular 2 and ng2-charts for a dashboard that needs to display real-time data.

Currently, my problem is that when I change the data associated with the chart, the chart redraws all data points. As this data will be coming in on a second-by-second basis, this is not appropriate for my purpose.

I'd like to make something that looks like this demo: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update but I don't have the budget for highcharts.

My code is as follows:

component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass } from '@angular/common';

import { CHART_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/dashboard.component.css'],
    directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class DashboardComponent {
    // lineChart
    public lineChartData: Array<any> = [
        { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },
        { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B' },
        { data: [18, 48, 77, 9, 100, 27, 40], label: 'Series C' }
    ];
    public lineChartLabels: Array<any> = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
    public lineChartOptions: any = {
        responsiveAnimationDuration: 5000,
        animation: {},
        responsive: true
    };
    public lineChartColours: Array<any> = [
        { // grey
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
            pointBorderColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
        },
        { // dark grey
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
            pointBorderColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
        },
        { // grey
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
            pointBorderColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
        }
    ];
    public lineChartLegend: boolean = true;
    public lineChartType: string = 'line';

    public randomize(): void {
        let _lineChartData: Array<any> = new Array(this.lineChartData.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < this.lineChartData.length; i++) {
            _lineChartData[i] = { data: new Array(this.lineChartData[i].data.length), label: this.lineChartData[i].label };
            for (let j = 0; j < this.lineChartData[i].data.length; j++) {
                _lineChartData[i].data[j] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            }
        }
        this.lineChartData = _lineChartData;
    }

    // events
    public chartClicked(e: any): void {
        console.log(e);
    }

    public chartHovered(e: any): void {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

component.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <base-chart class="chart"
                    [datasets]="lineChartData"
                    [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                    [options]="lineChartOptions"
                    [colors]="lineChartColours"
                    [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                    [chartType]="lineChartType"
                    (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                    (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></base-chart>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="randomize()">Randomize Data</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I can make this smoothly animate as the data changes, rather than it redrawing the entire graph?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement a push method for new data, like this:

```
public pushOne(): void {
    this.lineChartData.forEach((x, i) => {
      const num = this.generateNumber(i);
      const data: number[] = x.data as number[];
      data.push(num);
    });
    this.lineChartLabels.push(`Label ${this.lineChartLabels.length}`);
  }
```

You could also use the @ViewChild decorator to programmatically controls the render (or not rendered) part of the chart:

```
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective, { static: true }) chart: BaseChartDirective;
```